Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices. Then $A\geq B$ if and only if $\rho(BA^{-1})\leq 1$
Mostly what the title says. We have further that $A$ is positive definite and $B$ is positive semi definite. Assuming that $A\geq B$, I am able to conclude that:
$$x^*(I-BA^{-1})x = x^*(A-B)A^{-1}x \geq 1-\lambda$$
Where $x$ is the eigenvalue associated with $BA^{-1}$. What I want to say now is that:
$$1-\lambda \geq 0 \to 1\geq \lambda$$
which would (perhaps) imply that $\rho(BA^{-1})\leq 1$. But I am not convinced at all if that is a valid approach. Furthermore, I am not sure how to move in the opposite direction (though I suspect that if this technique works, the implication this flows backwards). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

hint: $\rho(BA^{-1})= \rho\big(A^\frac{-1}{2}BA^\frac{-1}{2})$

You mean that $x$ is an eigenvector (of unit length) with associated eigenvalue $\lambda$.  But I don't see how you arrive at the $\ge 1-\lambda$.

You are correct, $x$ is associated to $\lambda$. If $x$ has unit length, then we have equality. My mistake. It is also implied (though I should have made it explicit) that $BA^{-1}x= \lambda x$. I hope it is now clear how I reached that conclusion @TedShifrin

No, it isn't clear to me. $x$ is an eigenvector of $BA^{-1}$, but you're assuming $A\ge B$ here. So I still don't follow.

Perhaps this post or this will help. Simultaneous diagonalization of quadratic forms, one of which is positive definite, used to be a standard topic. :)

Interesting, I will certainly look into those! Thanks! Truthfully I think I am just lost in trying to relate the concepts of positive semi definite and the spectral radius of their "product". Hopefully those sources will help! Thanks!
